# Getting tweets specific to the USA with Twitterstream Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter, rubygems

I have a question about using the tweetstream gem! I am currently downloading a 1% stream from twitter right now but I want to be able to download tweets filtered only in the lower 48 United States, is there any way I am able to do this with this (or other) gems? Here is the code I have so far. Any and all help is appreciated!

Thanks,
-Ben

```
require 'tweetstream'

TweetStream.configure do |config|
    config.consumer_key = ####
    config.consumer_secret = ####
    config.oauth_token = ###
    config.oauth_token_secret = ####
    config.auth_method = :oauth
end

TweetStream::Client.new.sample do |status|
    puts "#{status.user.screen_name}: #{status.text}"
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out (with some help!).

I just used TweetStream::Client.new.locations('-125.00','25.0','-70.00','50.00', nil) do 
and it worked!